# How to amend a PHP string with values from another string

Tags: php, string

I am writing a PHP script that should amend the numbers in an original string based on values appearing on the second string as described below

I have an original string `$original="A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 E0 AB0 AC0";`
assuming I have a second string  `$data="B6 F12 AC20";`

I want to amend the first string as follows with the numbers in the second string replacing the Zeros(0) in the first string based on the Letter under which they appear.

`$original="A0 B6 C0 D0 E0 F12 E0 AB0 AC20";`

Comment: How many digits do the numbers for each letter in $data have? Is it 2 digits max? It would be easier to solve if you had some delimiter char in $data like the whitespace between the params in $original.

Comment: The digits can be 3 maximum

Comment: Next time, please show your attempts at the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some additional fixing thanks to @Emi**

---

This fixed it:

```
$original="A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 E0 AB0 AC0";
$data="B6 F12 AC20";

$data_array = explode(' ', $data);

foreach($data_array as $data_entry) {
    $letters = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/','',$data_entry); // Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string
    $len = strlen($letters)+1;
    if(substr($original, 0, $len) != $letters . 0){
        $original = str_replace(' '.$letters . 0, ' '.$data_entry, $original);
    } else {
        $original = $data_entry . substr($original, $len, strlen($original)-$len);
    }
}
echo $original;
```

I have added spaces between the `$data` values so PHP can "explode" it into an array object. Then, I loop through that array and get the first character of each array value, which will be a letter in this case. After that I perform a str_replace and paste a "0" after the `$letter` variable. Then, I override the value of $original to meet your requirements. Finally I echo out the value of $original, which is the result you'd like to see.

Comment: This won't work for more than one letter which OP needs.

Comment: Yes, mikag2014 edited his question afterwards so that there are now terms with two literals...

Comment: I have changed the code again to handle that problem as well ;)

Comment: Cool, but why the `for` loop? The `foreach` eliminates some overhead (like `sizeof`, `$i`, and the comparison operation between `$i` and the `sizeof` function each time) and also makes the code a bit cleaner. Not to nitpick but no one ever opts for a `for` loop when `foreach` can be used

Comment: Thanks @sjagr I have now updated the code to use the for-each structure.

Comment: The string does not get amended after using the above code by Robin and the output remains as A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 E0 AB0 AC0

Comment: @mikag2014 I have just updated the code a second ago. Give it another try ;)

Comment: @mikag2014 I have removed the `^` from the regex to solve that problem. But you can just re-copy and paste the code above to test it.

Comment: @Robin you still have a bug in it.

Comment: @Emi Could you tell me what the bug is exactly?

Comment: `foreach($data_array as $data_entry)`

`{`

    `$letters = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/','',$data_entry);`

    `//because str_replace - Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string`

    `$len = strlen($letters)+1;`

    `if(substr($original, 0, $len) != $letters . 0){`

        `$original = str_replace(' '.$letters . 0, ' '.$data_entry, $original);`

    `} else {`

        `$original = $data_entry . substr($original, $len, strlen($original)-$len);`

    `}`

`}`

I think this is the right way

Comment: @Emi I see, that's another way to tackle the issue. I just kept it basic this time ;) But your solution works as well!

Comment: @Robin it's taken from your solution, I just check the first letter since str_replace will find all occurrences and replace them, for example `$data="B6...` will also trigger a replacement for AB0.
So using the white space when matching should take care of that.